# asp.net inserting records into a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-webpages

I am trying to learn asp.net and I am trying to add values to a database upon submission. After submission, I am getting an error message that says, "Must declare the scalar variable "@4". I am not sure what I am doing wrong and how to fix this error.

Below is my code

```
    @using WebMatrix.Data;
    @{


        var db = Database.Open("Database");

        var commandText = "SELECT * FROM ShoppingCartData";
        var pid = 1111;
        var pname = "Hangover";
        var unitprice = 23.54;
        var quantity = 1;

        if (IsPost)
        {

            var q2 = "INSERT INTO CartItems (PID, PName, UnitPrice, Quantity) VALUES (@1, @2, @3, @4)";
            db.Execute(q2, pid, pname, unitprice, quantity);
        }

    }

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Add to database</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: beige;
                font-family: Verdana, Arial;
                margin: 50px;
            }

            form {
                padding: 10px;
                border-style: solid;
                width: 250px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="" method="post">
            <p>
            Add entry to database
            <p><input type="submit" value="Add" /></p>
        </form>



        <table>

            <caption>Print out newly added row</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var row in db.Query(commandText))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@row.PID</td>
                    <td>@row.PName</td>
                    <td>@row.UnitPrice</td>
                    <td>@row.Quantity</td>

                </tr>
            }
        </table> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your SQL command parameters, begin with a 0 index:

```
var q2 = "INSERT INTO CartItems (PID, PName, UnitPrice, Quantity) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)";
```